# Java ActionListener will not add to balance

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JeremysSodaMachine extends JApplet
{
   // Constant and regular variables
   private final int MACHINE_HEIGHT = 500;
   private final int MACHINE_WIDTH = 300;
   private final int MACHINE_X = 170;
   private final int MACHINE_Y = 120;
   private final int DRINK_BUTTON_HEIGHT = 50;
   private final int DRINK_BUTTON_WIDTH = 30;   
   private final int COINSLOT_HEIGHT = 5;
   private final int COINSLOT_WIDTH = 3;   
   private final int COINRETURN_HEIGHT = 4;
   private final int COINRETURN_WIDTH = 4;   
   private final int SODADISPENSER_HEIGHT = 20;
   private final int SODADISPENSER_WIDTH = 40;   
   private final int COIN5_HEIGHT = 30;
   private final int COIN5_WIDTH = 30;   
   private final int COIN10_HEIGHT = 30;
   private final int COIN10_WIDTH = 30;   
   private final int COIN25_HEIGHT = 30;
   private final int COIN25_WIDTH = 30;
   private final int DOLLAR_HEIGHT = 30;
   private final int DOLLAR_WIDTH = 30;
   private JPanel buttonPanel;
   private JButton cola;
   private JButton sprite;
   private JButton grape;
   private JButton rootbeer;
   private JButton water;
   private JButton coin5;
   private JButton coin10;
   private JButton coin25;
   private JButton dollar;
   private JButton coinReturnBtn;
   private JButton coinSlot;
   private JButton coinReturnSlot;
   private JButton sodaDispenser;
   private JLabel drinkCost;
   private JButton cokeSoldOut;
   private JButton spriteSoldOut;
   private JButton grapeSoldOut;
   private JButton rootbeerSoldOut;
   private JButton waterSoldOut;
   private JTextField dollarAmount;

   // Variable
   Image background;

   // init method
   public void init()
   {
      // Set layout manager to null
      // to use absolute coordinates
      setLayout(null);

      // Set size of applet
      setSize(500,575);

      // Set the background color to white.
      getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      ImageIcon coinReturnSlot2, sodaDispenser2,
                coinSlot2;


      // Call the base class paint method.
      super.paint(g);

      // Draw the outline of the soda machine.
      drawMachine(g);

      // Place background image on soda machine
      background = getImage(getCodeBase(), "coke_background.jpg");

      // Position and resize background image
      int width = background.getWidth (this);
      int height = background.getHeight (this);

      width = (width/2)+78;
      height = (height/2)+226;

      g.drawImage(background, 171, 121, width, height, this);

      // Create drink cost button
      drinkCost = new JLabel("75\u00A2");

      // Change drink cost font
      Font cost = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18);
      drinkCost.setFont(cost);

      // Sets the JLabel to opaque background
      drinkCost.setOpaque(true);

      drinkCost.setBackground(Color.red);

      setVisible(true);

      // Add drink cost button
      add(drinkCost);

      // Position and resize drink cost button
      drinkCost.setLocation(345, 121);
      drinkCost.setSize(30, 30);

      // Get coin slot image
      coinSlot2 = new ImageIcon("coinSlot.jpg");

      // Create coin slot button
      coinSlot = new JButton();

      // Set coin slot image to button
      coinSlot.setIcon(coinSlot2);

      // Add coin slot button
      add(coinSlot);

      // Position and resize coin slot button
      coinSlot.setLocation(405, 240);
      coinSlot.setSize(20, 35);

      // Create dollar amount button
      dollarAmount = new JTextField(5);
      dollarAmount.setText("0.00");
      dollarAmount.setEditable(false);

      // Add dollar amount button
      add(dollarAmount);

      // Position and resize dollar amount button
      dollarAmount.setLocation(320, 245);
      dollarAmount.setSize(70, 25);

      // Get coin return slot image
      coinReturnSlot2 = new ImageIcon("coinReturnSlot.jpg");

      // Create coin return slot button
      coinReturnSlot = new JButton();

      // Set coin return slot image to button
      coinReturnSlot.setIcon(coinReturnSlot2);

      // Add coin return slot button
      add(coinReturnSlot);

      // Position and resize coin return slot button
      coinReturnSlot.setLocation(405, 420);
      coinReturnSlot.setSize(20, 20);

      // Get soda dispenser image
      sodaDispenser2 = new ImageIcon("sodaDispenser.jpg");

      // Create soda dispenser button
      sodaDispenser = new JButton();

      // Set soda dispenser image to button
      sodaDispenser.setIcon(sodaDispenser2);

      // Add soda dispenser button
      add(sodaDispenser);

      // Position and resize soda dispenser button
      sodaDispenser.setLocation(390, 505);
      sodaDispenser.setSize(50, 30);


      buildCoinButtons();
      buildDrinkButtons();

   }

   private void buildCoinButtons()
   {
      // Variables
      ImageIcon nickle, dime, quarter, dollar2,
                coinReturnBtn2;

      // Get nickle image
      nickle = new ImageIcon("nickle.jpg");

      // Create nickle button
      coin5 = new JButton();

      // Set nickle image to button
      coin5.setIcon(nickle);

      // Add nickle button
      add(coin5);

      // Position and resize nickle button
      coin5.setLocation(215, 200);
      coin5.setSize(40, 25);

      // Get dime image
      dime = new ImageIcon("dime.jpg");

      // Create dime button
      coin10 = new JButton();

      // Set dime image to button
      coin10.setIcon(dime);

      // Add dime button
      add(coin10);

      // Position and resize dime button
      coin10.setLocation(275, 200);
      coin10.setSize(40, 25);


      // Get quarter image
      quarter = new ImageIcon("quarter.jpg");

      // Create quarter button
      coin25 = new JButton();

      // Set quarter image to button
      coin25.setIcon(quarter);

      // Sets actions preformed for coin25
      coin25.addActionListener(new coinHandler());

      // Add quarter button
      add(coin25);

      // Position and resize quarter button
      coin25.setLocation(335, 200);
      coin25.setSize(40, 25);

      // Get dollar coin image
      dollar2 = new ImageIcon("dollar.jpg");

      // Create dollar coin button
      dollar = new JButton();

      // Set dollar coin image to button
      dollar.setIcon(dollar2);

      // Add dollar coin button
      add(dollar);

      // Sets actions preformed for dollar
      dollar.addActionListener(new coinHandler());

      // Position and resize dollar coin button
      dollar.setLocation(395, 200);
      dollar.setSize(40, 25);

      // Get coin return button image
      coinReturnBtn2 = new ImageIcon("coinReturnBtn.jpg");

      // Create coin return button
      coinReturnBtn = new JButton();

      // Set coin return button image to button
      coinReturnBtn.setIcon(coinReturnBtn2);

      // Add coin return button
      add(coinReturnBtn);

      // Position and resize coin return button
      coinReturnBtn.setLocation(385, 285);
      coinReturnBtn.setSize(55, 35);
   } 

   private void buildDrinkButtons()
   {   
      // Variables
      ImageIcon coinSlot2,coke, 
                sprite2, grape2,
                rootbeer2, water2;      

      // Get coke image
      coke = new ImageIcon("coke.jpg");

      // Create coke button
      cola = new JButton();

      // Set coke image to button
      cola.setIcon(coke);

      // Add coke button
      add(cola);

      // Position and resize coke button
      cola.setLocation(335, 305);
      cola.setSize(25, 45);

      // Get sprite image
      sprite2 = new ImageIcon("sprite.jpg");

      // Create sprite button
      sprite = new JButton();

      // Set sprite image to button
      sprite.setIcon(sprite2);

      // Add sprite button
      add(sprite);

      // Position and resize sprite button
      sprite.setLocation(335, 355);
      sprite.setSize(25, 45);

      // Get grape image
      grape2 = new ImageIcon("grape.jpg");

      // Create grape button
      grape = new JButton();

      // Set grape image to button
      grape.setIcon(grape2);

      // Add grape button
      add(grape);

      // Position and resize grape button
      grape.setLocation(335, 405);
      grape.setSize(25, 45);

      // Get root beer image
      rootbeer2 = new ImageIcon("rootbeer.jpg");

      // Create root beer button
      rootbeer = new JButton();

      // Set root beer image to button
      rootbeer.setIcon(rootbeer2);

      // Add root beer button
      add(rootbeer);

      // Position and resize root beer button
      rootbeer.setLocation(335, 455);
      rootbeer.setSize(25, 45);

      // Get water image
      water2 = new ImageIcon("water.jpg");

      // Create water button
      water = new JButton();

      // Set water image to button
      water.setIcon(water2);

      // Add water button
      add(water);

      // Position and resize water button
      water.setLocation(335, 505);
      water.setSize(25, 45);

      // Create coke sold out button
      cokeSoldOut = new JButton("Sold Out");

      // Change coke sold out font
      Font cSoldOut = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
      cokeSoldOut.setFont(cSoldOut);

      // Add coke sold out button
      add(cokeSoldOut);

      // Position and resize coke sold out button
      cokeSoldOut.setLocation(215, 315);
      cokeSoldOut.setSize(100, 25);

      // Create sprite sold out button
      spriteSoldOut = new JButton("Sold Out");

      // Change sprite sold out font
      Font sSoldOut = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
      spriteSoldOut.setFont(sSoldOut);

      // Add sprite sold out button
      add(spriteSoldOut);

      // Position and resize sprite sold out button
      spriteSoldOut.setLocation(215, 365);
      spriteSoldOut.setSize(100, 25);

      // Create grape sold out button
      grapeSoldOut = new JButton("Sold Out");

      // Change grape sold out font
      Font gSoldOut = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
      grapeSoldOut.setFont(gSoldOut);

      // Add grape sold out button
      add(grapeSoldOut);

      // Position and resize grape sold out button
      grapeSoldOut.setLocation(215, 415);
      grapeSoldOut.setSize(100, 25);

      // Create root beer sold out button
      rootbeerSoldOut = new JButton("Sold Out");

      // Change root beer sold out font
      Font rbSoldOut = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
      rootbeerSoldOut.setFont(rbSoldOut);

      // Add root beer sold out button
      add(rootbeerSoldOut);

      // Position and resize root beer sold out button
      rootbeerSoldOut.setLocation(215, 465);
      rootbeerSoldOut.setSize(100, 25);

      // Create water sold out button
      waterSoldOut = new JButton("Sold Out");

      // Change water sold out font
      Font wSoldOut = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
      waterSoldOut.setFont(wSoldOut);

      // Add water sold out button
      add(waterSoldOut);

      // Position and resize water sold out button
      waterSoldOut.setLocation(215, 515);
      waterSoldOut.setSize(100, 25);

   }

   private void drawMachine(Graphics g)
   {
      // Draw a black unfilled rectangle.
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawRect(MACHINE_X, MACHINE_Y, MACHINE_WIDTH, MACHINE_HEIGHT);

      // Draw the top and side 3D area and fill black.
      int[] xCoords = {90, 390, 470, 170};

      int[] yCoords = {70, 70, 120, 120};

      int[] xCoords1 = {90, 90, 170, 170 };

      int[] yCoords1 = {70, 540, 620, 120};

      g.fillPolygon(xCoords, yCoords, 4);

      g.fillPolygon(xCoords1, yCoords1, 4);
    }

   private class coinHandler implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         double dR = 1.00;
         double qR = 0.25;
         double dM = 0.10;
         double nL = 0.05;

         double balance = Double.parseDouble(dollarAmount.getText());

         if(e.getSource() == dollar)
         {
            balance += 1.0;
         }
         else
         {
           if(e.getSource() == coin25)
           {
               balance += 0.25;
           }
            //else if()
            //{

            //}
            //else if()
            //{

            //}

         }
         dollarAmount.setText(""+ balance);
      }
   }
}
```

I've tried everything but I can't get the JButtons to work with the ActionListener to add money to the balance. I've added the object for the ActionListener, created the methods for the ActionListener, and whenever I click on a button it doesn't work; dollarAmount goes to 0.0. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't update/modify/change the state of the component (or any other component) from within any paint method, directly or indirectly.  Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to see how painting actually works.  Based on you code, there is no need to override paint at all

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `dollarAmount` to `0.00` in the `paint()` method.  `paint()` is called each time anything changes on the component.  So no matter what you change `dollarAmount` to in the listener, it will be reset to zero in the `paint()` method - which will always be called as you've changed the text of a component in your `JApplet`.

You need to move the initialisation of the components out of the `paint()` method.  In fact, on a quick read through your code, you probably want to move almost all of the code in your `paint()` method into `init()`.

To verify for yourself the flow of what is happening - put in some debugging - e.g. `System.out.println` of `dollarAmount` in the `coinHandler.actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: Good catch. I missed it was in the paint; the debugger was saying event.getSource() != dollar, although i just pressed that button --> ???

Comment: Thanks, J Richard Snape! I really appreciate the help! It works now!

Comment: @J Richard Snape, today is my first day using Stackoverflow. How do I search for other answered questions in here? Need help with 4 other areas in my Soda Machine applet program and want to see if the answer to my questions have already been answered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jeremy - welcome to stack overflow! There are a few ways to search. I usually start with google and with the right terms, often Stack overflow links come high up.  Within the site - you can use the search button at the top right.  I usually use it in combination with the tags system, which is most powerful.  If you select the Java tag and (optionally) the swing tag, you will narrow down the answers you're seeing. You can include tag names in search by enclosing them in square brackets.  [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) might help too (Help centre on searching)